I getting access denied error for bucket GCP
This is structure
From Load Balancer -> Bucket GCP
Bucket not public.
I need to deploy frontend on GCP bucket access only throgh Load balancer.
Like in AWS we only access S3 using Cloudfront not directly accessible.
Please tell what do and is there any alternative in GCP to deploy frontend
google-cloud-storage
Please tell what do and is there any alternative in GCP to deploy frontend

For using load balancer in front fo gcs, bucket should be publicly readable, every person can only read your content so you should not include sensitive information in your public buckets, you can choose a bucket name that not related to your domain name (I mean it is preferable to make bucket name complicated to determine it by another users).
And there is another alternative for this:
Example:

cloud run or appengine : it can be private by setting ingress to "internal and load balancer" and you can activate CDN within your load balancer

